# Pulling remote changes from a development server in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

For most projects, I work in a local Dockerized setup, but once in awhile, I have to work on a project that lives on a remote development server. Using `tools > deployment > configuration`, I have set up sftp access to the server.

Now I can't seem to find a way to download the relevant files from that server.

I could swear that there used to be a menu option under `Tools > Deployment` to do this. Something like `pull files from server.`

Did this option go away with a recent update? Is there another way to do this from within the IDE (preferably without pushing to version control every time I want to test a change)?

===

Edit: I am using PhpStorm 2019.2. The contents of the `Deployment` submenu are:

- Configuration
- Options
- Automatic Upload
- Browse Remote Host

I have tested the sftp connection from within the configuration screen in PhpStorm, and it is working. `Browse Remote Host` also appears to work.

Comment: What version of PhpStorm are you using? What menu items do you see under Tools > Deployment? There should be options like "Compare with Deployed..." and "Sync with Deployed..." if the configuration is set up correctly.

Comment: Thanks, Jason. I edited my question to include this information.

Comment: In the configuration did you set the sftp connection to be the default connection?

Comment: Make sure that Deployment entry is configured properly (no warnings on other tabs) -- most often ppl forgetting to set the path mapping (as simple as `/`)